# window leak with alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an app that queries the phone's db for messages. If the cursor comes back with messages in it then i am trying to display each message in an alertdialog one after another. I'm getting the following error saying that there has been a window leak.

I think it's to do with the alertdialog not being cancelled properly before the next is shown. Does anyone know why i'm getting this error?

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
      Cursor c = nfcScannerApplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromMessage();

        Log.e(TAG, "messages in db = " +  c.getCount());


            if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0){
                c.moveToFirst();

                while(c.moveToNext()){

                final String guid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_MESSAGE_GUID));
                final String message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_MESSAGE_TEXT));
                final String createdAt = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_MESSAGE_CREATED_AT));
                final String sender = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_MESSAGE_SENDER));


                DateTime dt = new DateTime(createdAt);
                DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("H:mm d-MMM-Y");
                String date = fmt2.print(dt);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        this);

                    // set title
               alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("You have a new message : " );

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage(  "\n" + message + "\n"
                                + "From : " + sender + " at " + date + "\n"+"Click OK to confirm message read")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                                nfcScannerApplication.loginValidate.deleteMessage(guid);

                                Cursor c = nfcScannerApplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromMessage();
                                Log.e(TAG, "message count = " + c.getCount());

                                //send guid back to martin so he can delete message on server
                                String[] params = new String[]{guid};
                                AsyncCompleteMessage ascm = new AsyncCompleteMessage();
                                ascm.execute(params);

                                finish();

                            }
                          });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); 

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();

                }//end of while
            }else{

                finish();
            }

    }
```

.

```
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605): Activity com.carefreegroup.DisplayMessageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418e0ac8 that was originally added here
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.carefreegroup.DisplayMessageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@418e0ac8 that was originally added here
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:465)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:419)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:558)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at com.carefreegroup.DisplayMessageActivity.onResume(DisplayMessageActivity.java:103)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1266)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5148)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2997)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3055)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605): Activity com.carefreegroup.DisplayMessageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4152c258 that was originally added here
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.carefreegroup.DisplayMessageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4152c258 that was originally added here
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:465)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:419)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:351)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:558)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at com.carefreegroup.DisplayMessageActivity.onResume(DisplayMessageActivity.java:103)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1266)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5148)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2997)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3055)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
02-13 11:33:13.602: E/WindowManager(19605):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `dialog.dismiss();` before calling `finish()` in your `onClick()` method as in the following code..

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                            nfcScannerApplication.loginValidate.deleteMessage(guid);

                            Cursor c = nfcScannerApplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromMessage();
                            Log.e(TAG, "message count = " + c.getCount());

                            //send guid back to martin so he can delete message on server
                            String[] params = new String[]{guid};
                            AsyncCompleteMessage ascm = new AsyncCompleteMessage();
                            ascm.execute(params);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();

                        }
```

Comment: Hi, i have no reference to a dialog within the onclick. For example i can go this.dismissDialog(int), but i have no dialog with an integer id

Comment: check my code.. you can use dialog interface for calling the dismiss.. that what i am doing in my code...

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.Check this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)